# Using integer as type of _id return HTTP 400 for item_lookup

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

My setting is something like below, which the main identifier _id use integer type.

When I tried to access an item (it's exist on the db) using this URL: http://xxxxxxx/promotions/1485919019667 , it returns HTTP 404.

I wonder whether it's not possible to use type other than ObjectID for _id ?

```
promotions = {
    'item_title': 'promotion',
    'item_url' : 'regex("[\d]+")',
    'item_lookup': True,
    'schema': {
        '_id': {
            'type': 'integer',
            'minlength': 13,
            'maxlength': 13,
            'required': True,
            'unique': True
        },
        'category': {
            'type': 'string',
            'allowed': ["MARKETPLACE", "ELAUGETS", "FASHNESS", "FRINKS", "TRENTER", "OTHERS"]
        },
        'card_id': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'maxlength': 50
        },
        'title': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 5,
            'maxlength': 200,
            'required': True
        },
        'description': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 5,
            'maxlength': 2500,
            'required': True
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea guys ?

Comment: I suggest you to set another field to be used as ID field in global or resource settings with `id_field` setting. See [here](http://python-eve.org/config.html#resource-item-endpoints), but I don't know what happens when adding a field in the schema with same name as the default `_id` field.

Comment: for that, then I will have unnecessary field in my document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Handling custom ID fields](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/custom_idfields.html) in the documentation? Quoting from the heading of that page:

> However, you might have collections where your unique identifier is not and ObjectId, and you still want individual document endpoints to work properly. Don’t worry, it’s doable, it only requires a little tinkering.

The tutorial covers `UUID` fields, but is good for any custom type really.